# ngIf and ngFor Not Working inside Ionic 5 (Angular 9) component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I was refactoring a project and moved a module to anothr place.

It seems that NgIf or NgOf are not working anymore I tried with a basic code.

EDIT: I have this error : Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-list'.

I checked my imports and i import BrowserModule  in my main module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

My Html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
      <ion-buttons slot="start">
          <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
        </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Shopping Cart</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <div *ngIf="1 > 0">Hello</div>
</ion-content>
```

my Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { CartPageRoutingModule } from './cart-routing.module';

import { CartPage } from './cart.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    CartPageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [CartPage]
})
export class CartPageModule {}
```

my component import

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/@core/services/api.service';
import { Router, NavigationExtras } from '@angular/router';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
```

Comment: what is error ?

Comment: I don't have any error

Comment: So you are not seeing the div with Hello? there's not anything obviously wrong with what you provide, it should work. Have you inspected the elements? is the div present?

Comment: I'm not seeing it.The div isn't present in the browser insector